# Does ‘magnificent head’ sometimes mean ‘magnificent hair’?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

While searching the Net, ‘magnificent head’ shows me a lot of lion’s heads, but I found ‘a woman with a magnificent head’ in a book.

> “Fleur Delacour, though she demonstrated excellent use of the Bubble-Head Charm, was attacked by grindylows as she approached her goal, and failed to retrieve her hostage. We award her twenty-five points.”
>
> Applause from the stands.
>
> ”I deserved zero,” said Fleur throatily, shaking her **magnificent head.** (*Harry Potter 4* [US Version]: p.506)[Bold font is mine]

**N.B.:** The scene is after Triwizard Tournament. The judges are criticizing and giving points to performers. Fleur, whose hair is beautiful, isn’t satisfied with her own performance.

I tried looking for ‘magnificent *hair*’ on the Net, which showed me a lot of beautiful hairs. Why does the author write ‘magnificent head’ instead of ‘magnificent hair’? Does it have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ‘magnificent head’ sometimes mean ‘magnificent hair’?

Yes, "Magnificent head" is used to refer to very nice hair. It sounds wrong, but it's short for the term "Magnificent head of hair."

"magnificent hair" and "magnificent head" has the same meaning and both refer to beautiful hair. I the only difference is the usage. If Fleur was to shake her "magnificent hair", it'd be a different action from shaking her magnificent head. "Shaking her magnificent hair" would be used for example, if Fleur was taking off her beanie, and was shaking her hair to kind of straighten it. That's when "magnificent hair" is used instead of "head".

"Head" is used when Fleur is shaking her head in a way that is disapproval, or decline, as in no.